# Inside "Find in path" dialog, make the return key go to file, not open the panel

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

When I use the find in path dialog, if I click the desired file with the mouse (double click) it will take me to that file, but if I use the return/enter key it will open the "Find Occurrences of..." panel, and even there it will highlight the first option, not the highlighted one I picked in the dialog.

If there a keyboard way to mimic the mouse double click and be taken to the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **Jump to Source** action (shortcut can be changed in the Keymap settings, default is <kbd>F4</kbd> in most cases).